# Error when modifying Django data from HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I have a small error when trying to modify data stored in Django Oracle, when trying to add the link that takes me to the function and modifies me the user throws me the following error:

> NoReverse Match at/administration
>
> Reverse for 'editar/' not found.
>
> 'editar/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I leave you part of my code

**`urls.py`**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = "index"),
    path('galery', views.galery, name = "galery"),
    path('toregister', views.toregister, name = "toregister"),
    path('register', views.register, name = "register"),
    path('administration', views.administration, name = "administration"),
    path('editar/<int:id>', views.editar, name = "editar")
]
```

**`views.py:`**

```py
def administration(request):
     #Administracion
     usuarios = Usuario.objects.all()
     datos = {
         'usuarios': usuarios
     }
     return render(request, 'store/administration.html', datos)

def editar(request, id):
     usuario = Usuario.objects.get(id = id)
     if request.method == 'GET':
         form = UsuarioForm(instance = usuario)
         contexto = {
         'form': form
         }
     return render(request, 'store/register.html', contexto)
```

**`models.py:`**

```py
class Usuario(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Nombre del Usuario')
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Apellidos del Usuario')
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = 'Email del Usuario')
    rut = models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key = True, verbose_name = 'Rut del Usuario', unique = True)
    contraseña = models.CharField(max_length = 15, verbose_name = 'Contraseña del Usuario')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rut
```

**`administration.html:`**

```html
<tbody>
    {% for users in usuarios %}
        <tr>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.nombre}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.apellidos}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.rut}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.email}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4"><a href="{% url 'editar/' users.id %}" class="p-2">Editar</a><br><a href="">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

It’s my first time posting here, any other code you need or information you can let me know and I’ll send it to you. Also if I posted something wrong or not in the right way or format, any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the slash from your URL

```
{% url 'editar' users.id %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple apps, you can add app_name to urls.py

```
app_name = '<your app name>'
urlpatterns = [
     ---
]
```

You can write the following in your template:

```
<a href="{% url '<your app name>:editar' users.id %}></a>
```